# MAMP PHP Mac OSX Header Not working

Tags: php, session, redirect, http-headers, dreamweaver

I've installed MAMP on a mac desktop running 10.6.8. I'm using dreamweaver as the IDE to develop my website. I have written my webpage in php, I can preview it in the browser and I can see eveything, so the server and that stuff works. But in my first page i have this line:

```
session_start();
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (!empty($_POST["Reg_type"])) {
        $_SESSION["regtype"]=$_POST["Reg_type"];
        header("Location: Page2.php");
        var_dump($_SERVER);
    }
}
```

So once the user selects a radio button from the form and clicks submit, it'll take them to the 2nd page. I **know** that it's going into the loop with the header but for some reason it is unable to redirect to page2. When I click an option and hit submit it just goes to page1 again. I think there might be a problem with the php.ini file dealing with header redirects of sessions, i have no idea. I am a newbie to macs. Does anyone know what the problem could be? Thank you

Comment: Why is this form processing code not located in the Page2.php script if you are going there anyway?

Comment: Could you please provide a form code?

Comment: Technically speaking, `Location: Page2.php` is invalid.  RFC 1945 requires an absolute URI, rather than a relative one.  But that's probably not the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

If Dreamweaver auto generated your code, check the line were the form tag is declared.  If it looks like:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
```

then page1.php will reload, because it is calling itself.  It would likely be cleaner to just change the form tag to

```
<form method="POST" action="page2.php">
```

and drop the whole if statement.

On submit page2.php will be loaded and that script/page will have $_POST['Reg_Type'] available for processing.  Then if you need to assign $_POST['Reg_Type'] to a session variable, I would do it on page2.php.

And BTW, non of the above is exclusive to Mac.